# Angular Bind value to another array by ID

Tags: angularjs

I have a list objects that are displayed in a ng-Repeat.

```
<tr ng-repeat="group in Groups">
  <td>{{group.Description}}</td>
  ...
  <td>{{group.ControlModeID}}</td>
  <td>{{group.EnergyStore}}</td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to display `group.ControlModeID` as Description field in an object array defined by ID and Description:

```
var ModeList = [
   {ID: 1, Description: "ContrlDescription1"},
   {ID: 2, Description: "ContrlDescription2"},
];
```

It can be accomplished within a ng model as follows

```
ng-model="group.ControlModeID" ng-options="obj.ID as obj.Description for obj in ModeList"
```

But I need to use it within the `{{}}` brackets.

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do. Could you describe what you have and what exactly your goal is? Fiddle would also be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now `ModeList` is an array of objects with no, as I assume here, relationship between `ID` and array index (despite both being sequential numbers in the example).

You need to change `ModeList` to an object where each key is the `ID` and expose it on the scope.

```
$scope.ModeList = {
  1: {ID: 1, Description: "ContrlDescription1"},
  2: {ID: 2, Description: "ContrlDescription2"},
};
```

Then, you could do

```
<td>{{ModeList[group.ControlModeID]}}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you @NewDev, that is exactly what I need. I will sort the array to use the ID as index in the array so that the <td>{{ModeList[group.ControlModeID]}}</td> bit will work.

Comment: @ChrisMalherbe, If `ID`s make sense as an index - sure, but it is rarely the case. I would use an object instead. In any case, if the answer addressed your question, consider accepting